# moving GridView to the center of the div

Tags: html, css, asp.net, gridview, position

i know this question has been asked before. i have tried it all but nothing seems to be working. 
this is my HTML and CSS code..

```css
body {
    color: #666;
    font: 12px/17px Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(center top , #C9D3DF 0%, #FFF 100%) no-repeat scroll 0% 0% transparent !important;
    
}
#container{ 
    width:1349px;
    height:auto;
}

#wrapper{
    width:940px;
    height:auto;
    margin: 0px auto 0px auto;
    padding: 0px;
    position: static;
    box-shadow:2px 2px 5px 5px #888888;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px 5px #888888;
    -moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px 5px #888888;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    border-radius: 8px;
}

#header {
    margin: 0px auto 0px auto;
    padding: 0px;
    position: static;
    width: 940px;
    height: 169px;
        }

#contentholder {
    width:940px;
    height:111px;
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
}

#logo {
    margin:14px 0px 0px;
    height:67px;
    width:397px;
    padding:0px;
    float:left;
    overflow:hidden;
}

#linkholder {
    height:31px;
    width:323px;
    float:right;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0px 0px 2px;
    padding:5px;
}

#links {
    float: right;
    font-size:small;
    height: 0px;
    padding-right:7px;
    padding-top:3px;
    width: 176px;
}


#links li {
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 9px;
    float: left;
    height: 26px;
    display: inline;
    padding-right:15px;
    color:blue;
    padding:3px;
    border-radius:10px;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px 2px #888888;
    text-align:center;
}

#menu {
    width:940px;
    height:45px;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #0000FF;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    border-radius: 8px;
}

#menu ul {
    height: 31px;
    padding: 15px 0px 0px 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    overflow:hidden;
    }

#menu li {
    display: inline;
    padding: 20px; 
    text-align:center;
}

#image{
    width: 940px;
    height: 250px;
    margin: 0px auto 0px auto;
    padding: 0px;
    position: static;
    background-color: #0000FF;
}

#image img {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}

#mbody {
    height:auto;
    width:940px;
    margin: 0px auto 0px auto;
    padding: 0px;
    position: static;
}

#mbody h1 {
    text-align:center;
}

#text{
    width:800px;
    margin: 0px auto 0px auto;
    text-align:justify;
    padding: 0px 20px 0px 20px;
}

#footer {
    width: 940px;
    height:60px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#copyrt {
    text-align:center;
    color:gray;
    padding-top:20px;
}

#mission {
    width:46%;
    text-align:justify;
    float: left;
}

#mission h2 {
    text-align:center;
}

#vision {
    width:41%;
    text-align:justify;
    float: right;
}

#vision h2 {
    text-align:center;
}

.gview {
    height: 100px;
    width:200px;
    margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;
    box-shadow: 1px 2px 1px 2px #888888;
    position:relative;
}
```

```html
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <!-- header placement -->
        <div id="container">
            <div id="wrapper">
                <header id="header">
                    <div id="contentholder">
                        <span id="logo">
                            <img src="Images/logo.png" /></span>
                        <div id="linkholder">
                            <ul id="links">
                                <li>Admin Login</li>
                                <li>Register</li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!--Menu creation-->
                    <nav id="menu">
                        <ul>
                            <li>Home</li>
                            <li>Patient Care</li>
                            <li>Doctors</li>
                            <li>Appointments</li>
                            <li>Departments</li>
                            <li>Blood Bank</li>
                            <li>About Us</li>
                        </ul>
                    </nav>
                </header>
                <!-- Main image -->
                <div id="image">
                    <img src="/Images/cardio.jpg" alt="Cardiology" />
                </div>
                <!--Main content-->
                <div id="mbody">
                    <div id="text">
                        <h1>Department of Cardiology</h1>
                        <p>
                            Cardiovascular diseases are the main factor of death in the Western World, and they represent a challenge for diagnosis, treatment and research. Sigma Medicare is always prepared 
                        to provide patients with the most accurate diagnosis and professional manner of treatment. Our doctors are dedicated to your health. In addition to quality care, 
                        our department is also involved in teaching and numerous researches. 
                        </p>

                        <div class="gview">
                            <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="CID" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" FooterStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                                <Columns>
                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="CID" HeaderText="CID" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="CID" />
                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="Name" />
                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Designation" HeaderText="Designation" SortExpression="Designation" />
                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Qualification" HeaderText="Qualification" SortExpression="Qualification" />
                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Shift" HeaderText="Shift" SortExpression="Shift" />
                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Appointment_Timings" HeaderText="Appointment_Timings" SortExpression="Appointment_Timings" />
                                </Columns>
                            </asp:GridView>
                            <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:masterConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Cardiology]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!--Footer Content-->
                <footer id="footer">
                    <p id="copyrt">Copyright &copy 2015, by Sigma Medicare. All rights reserved.</p>
                </footer>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

Please note that container DIV is 800px. any kind of help will be greatly appreciated. I have tried everything that has been suggested before but nothing seems to be working.
Thanks.

Edit: @Lal: Entered whole code for the page and CSS..

Comment: its actually center aligned, check the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lalu050/ytasezLb/)..here i have specified a border just to show you..

Comment: hey thanks for your response.. I saw that but for some reason it's not in the center for me.. stays on the left side of the page.

Comment: May be in ur style you have something written for gridview which might be creating the problem

Comment: this div in enclosed in another div..  the CSS for that div is: height:auto;
    width:940px;
    margin: 0px auto 0px auto;
    padding: 0px;
    position: static;
Do you reckon that might be causing the trouble?

Comment: Just check the style using firebug or chrome's inspect element

Comment: wait..let me check it..

Comment: no..that is not creating any problem at all..see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/lalu050/ytasezLb/1/)..may be some other..

Comment: can you please post the full css and html..i'll just give a try..

Comment: edited the full css and html code. thank you very much!

Comment: its again center aligned..check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lalu050/rjLo7u56/)

Comment: i've editted the snippet in your question itself..check it..its already center aligned..

Comment: That is weird then. No idea why VS2013 is not showing it in the middle. Thanks for your help anyway!

Comment: you are checking this in visualstudio design view???oh god..run it in browser and only then you can trust what you have done..

Comment: http://prntscr.com/5lu4qy this is what it shows. No i have been checking it in the browser... Firefox and chrome..

Comment: Okk but what is the width of the grid view??? Inspect it in chrome

Comment: it is bound to the database, so depends on the data/columns.. i didn't set it myself.. its 604px, just inspected in chrome

Comment: May be that is the problem...try changing the width in chrome inspect element window itself..just set it to some 100px and check if it is center aligned

Comment: Sorted it, thanks. Included CssClass to the aspGridView control. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have no problem with the CSS, its correct. Actually the div is center aligned. I've edited the snippet in your question Itself. See it..

The problem is with the GridView. I think you have some CSS overriding the styles applied for the `gview`. So kindly check the styles applied for your GridView.